# Preventing memory leak in dependent functions

Tags: c, debugging, memory-leaks

*First of all, I don't even know how to adress this issue nor how to google a solution to it so if you have a better title that describes better my issue, that would be great.*

*Intro:* I'm currently developing C code for a project in school, the project is not really ambitious but I would like to it the right way. The project is a about a Hardware password manager.

One of the parts of the project is the feature of the device locking itself if no input is recieved in X seconds. I'm planning to achieve this through timers and interruptions (since I'm working on a microchip) but this has little to do with the real question here.

My initial design was, in the `main()` function call the function `lock()` so the device boots locked, once the correct PIN is provided, the function `MainMenu()` is called (inside the `lock()` scope). However, the `MainMenu()` has a `while(1) { some code }` which never returns anything because it doesn't need to. However, the next time the user is AFK, a interruption will trigger and `lock()` will be called, effectively saving the Program Counter of the `MainMenu()`. Once the user inputs the correct PIN, `lock()` will call `MainMenu()`. In other words, function `A` will call function `B` which will again call `A` and so on.

See the problem? I will be eternally saving local variables that will never be used (PC at the least). I have solved the problemwith some tweaks in the design. However, the question persists.

- Is there a way to call a function without saving the current envirionment on which I am?
- Is having a cyclic model of functions a real problem or can be solved by designing a good one and then implementing it? If so, what kind of solutions do developers use?

Edit1: One comment suggested `break`. This is not what I want because the problem is not inside a loop, but in 2 functions calling each other. Another comment suggested `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`. I think this functions are useful if you want to save the environment on which you are currently running. However, in my case, it's precisely the opposite, I do **not** want to save the environment on which I'm.

Comment: Please condense and show some code.

Comment: Are you looking for a [`break` statement?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_break_statement.htm)

Comment: Consider looping instead of recursing.

Comment: Maybe `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` are what you're looking for.

Comment: The code is not ready, it's just a design. I want to post the code but I'm afraid that wouldn't help solve my issue because there's no code, I've started some hours ago.

Comment: When you have enough code to post, this would probably be more appropriate for CodeReview.stackexchange.com. Broad design questions are not really on-topic here.

Comment: What does this question have to do with c++?

Comment: Sounds like you may want to switch to a state-machine structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A state machine sounds nice and sophisticated. The following design is a bit simpler. This is how I would do it:

```
/* locks screen
 *
 * Function does not return until valid keys for unlock have been entered.
 */
void lockScreen();

/* prints menu (may consider choice to highlight resp. item)
 */
void printMenu(int choice);

/* reads from keyboard
 *
 * returns: < 0 ... timeout
 *          >= 0 ... selected menu item
 */
int keyInput();

/* main function */
int main()
{
  int lastChoice = -1;
  for (bool lock = 1;;) { /* never ending run-time loop */
    if (lock) { lockScreen(); lock = 0; }
    printMenu(lastChoice);
    int choice = keyInput();
    switch (choice) {
      /* regular choices */
      /* exit required?
      case 0: return 0;
       */
      case 1: /* do 1st command */ break;
      case 2: /* do 2nd command */ break;
      default: /* should not happen */ break;
      /* timeout */
      case -1: lock = 1;
    }
    if (choice >= 0) lastChoice = choice;
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Please, consider this as sketch (not as [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). As the questioner didn't expose code or specific details of the intended platform, I tried to answer this "generically".
2. `lockScreen()` could use `keyInput()` as well. Thereby, keys could be collected until they form a complete password (which might be correct or wrong). The timeout could be used to reset an incomplete password.

Comment: That's the approach I decided to take